# Expand references to sibling values in a JSON using JQ

Tags: json, jq, nested-loops, lookup

I have a JSON document holding configurations with macros.  I need to expand macros that reference other elements.  For simplicity, consider this input document.

```
[
  {
    "first": "Tim",
    "Full": "{first} {last}",
    "last": "Smith"
  },
  {
    "first": "Jane",
    "Full": "{first} {last}",
    "last": "Doe"
  }
]
```

Performance is not paramount here so I don't mind blindly checking for every element occurring in every other element.

I worked out the following logic as a proof of concept.  But can't figure out how to add a nested loop on `$lookup` to update the other `with_entries` value.

```
jq  '
  .[]
| . as $lookup
| with_entries(
    .value=(
      .value
      | sub("{first}"; $lookup.first)
    )
  )
'
```

JQ processes streams of values/documents and it feels like I now need to work with two streams.  Which I hoped to accomplish by using `$lookup` for the back reference. Now I am stuck.

**SOLUTION**
*oguz ismail provided a great solution for the original question (Please give them a +1) that uses map_values().  It is very clear and I wanted to include it here for reference.  You will note that it uses a named group `(?<found_key>.*?)` in the regular expression (see oniguruma's [named group](https://github.com/kkos/oniguruma/blob/master/doc/RE))*

```
map(. as $lookup | map_values(gsub("\\{(?<found_key>.*?)\\}"; $lookup[.found_key])))
```

*I asked how to process when there are non-string elements in the structure.  Here is an example that includes an array of colors:*

```
[
  {
    "first": "Tim",
    "Full": "{first} {last}",
    "last": "Smith",
    "colors": ["red", "blue"]
  }
]
```

*oguz ismail provided a solution for this structure as well that only attempts to modify elements that are strings:*

```
map(
  . as $lookup
  | (.[] | strings)
  |= gsub("\\{(?<found_key>.*?)\\}"; $lookup[.found_key])
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `gsub` with a named capture group for expanding all the macros in a single run without hardcoding their names. And, `with_entries` doesn't help at all in this case; use `map_values` instead.

```
map(. as $lookup | map_values(gsub("\\{(?<found_key>.*?)\\}"; $lookup[.found_key])))
```

<sup>[Online demo](https://jqplay.org/s/sVpCZo5MfZ)</sup>

Comment: Great solution oguz.  I had to read a bit to figure out what you are doing with gsub().  Referencing as .key confused me because I wasn't sure if it was something provided by map() or map_values().  To make it clear to other users, can I suggest you change your example to:
map(. as $lookup | map_values(gsub("\\{(?<found_key>.*?)\\}"; $lookup[.found_key])))

Comment: @batchman Yup, that's clearer, updated now. You're welcome

Comment: Many thanks.  I over simplified my example.  There are other structures in my document.  I can fix errors by prefixing gsub with "strings |" but I can't figure out how to keep "children".  I appreciate your response and will open another question if you feel that makes sense.  However if you happen to know a quick answer then I will update my question to include the complication.  Example doc: [
  {
    "a": {"sub": "value"},
    "first": "Tim",
    "Full": "{first} ${last}",
    "last": "Smith"
  },
  {
    "first": "Jane",
    "Full": "{first} {last}",
    "last": "Doe"
  }
]

Comment: @batchman How about [this](https://jqplay.org/s/b317jT5SeJ)? If the actual input is even more complex than that, then you should post another question.

Comment: Perfection.  I included both solutions in my question with credits.  Many many thanks.